Best practices along with using VPN for remote access to VPC
I'm exploring the OpenVPN access server/ConexaCloud as I want to be able to access a VPC with private resources.
With OpenVPN, what other measures should I take to secure the VPC?
I know I can block  traffic on private resources using iptables or ufw, but I'd like to see if there are other things that can be done.

When you want to secure anything, you have to make it clear, from what you're securing. What are your possible threats? Without this, it's impossible to answer.

Depending on your organization's size and activities, you might want to consider assigning an expert in cybersecurity to keep your data safe.
However, here's our version of best practices.
Notice that it refers to another document: "The security policies".

Network Segmentation:
Create Subnets: Divide the VPC into multiple subnets based on functionality and security requirements (e.g., public, private, and database subnets).
Network ACLs: Use Network Access Control Lists (ACLs) to control inbound and outbound traffic to and from the subnets.

Security Groups:
Define Security Groups: Implement security groups to control inbound and outbound traffic to the resources. Be as restrictive as possible.
Least Privilege: Apply the principle of least privilege to ensure that only the necessary traffic is allowed.

Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA):
Enable MFA: Require MFA for accessing the OpenVPN server and for logging into any administrative interfaces.

Strong Authentication and Authorization:
Use Strong Password Policies: Enforce strong passwords and rotate them regularly.
Use Role-Based Access Control (RBAC): Implement RBAC to limit access based on user roles and responsibilities.

Encryption:
Encrypt Data in Transit: Ensure that all data in transit between the VPN client and the VPC is encrypted using strong protocols (e.g., AES-256).
Encrypt Data at Rest: Use encryption for data at rest within the VPC resources.

Logging and Monitoring:
Enable Logging: Enable logging for all VPC components, including OpenVPN, AWS CloudTrail, and VPC Flow Logs.
Monitor Logs: Regularly monitor and analyze logs for suspicious activity.
Set Up Alerts: Configure alerts for any unusual or unauthorized activities.

Patch Management:
Regular Updates: Keep the OpenVPN server, client software, and all VPC resources up to date with the latest security patches.
Automated Patching: Where possible, enable automated patching for critical components.

Firewalls and Intrusion Detection/Prevention Systems:
Firewalls: Utilize firewalls (e.g., AWS Security Groups, Network ACLs, iptables, ufw) to restrict access.
IDS/IPS: Deploy Intrusion Detection and Prevention Systems (IDS/IPS) to detect and prevent malicious activities.

Access Control:
Limit VPN User Access: Restrict VPN user access to only those who need it.
User Activity Audits: Regularly audit user activities and access levels.

Secure Configuration Management:
Configuration Reviews: Regularly review configurations for all VPC components to ensure they comply with security best practices.
Automated Compliance Checks: Use tools to automate compliance checks against the security policies.

Backup and Recovery:
Regular Backups: Perform regular backups of critical data and configurations.
Disaster Recovery Plan: Have a disaster recovery plan in place and test it regularly.

Security Awareness Training:
User Training: Provide security awareness training to users accessing the VPN and VPC.
Phishing Simulations: Conduct regular phishing simulations to educate users about recognizing and avoiding phishing attacks.


Good luck!

I love you <3333
